# How to prevent click on other tab in NonScrollableViewPager?

Tags: java, android, view, android-viewpager

I disable swipe the ViewPager with TabLayout as below:

```
public class NonScrollableViewPager extends ViewPager {

    public NonScrollableViewPager(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init(context, null);
    }

    public NonScrollableViewPager(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init(context, attrs);
    }

    private void init(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        setImportantForAccessibility(IMPORTANT_FOR_ACCESSIBILITY_NO);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        // Never allow swiping to switch between pages
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        // Never allow swiping to switch between pages
        return false;
    }
}
```

How to prevent other tabs clickable when select one of tabs, then computation complected then enable the clickable. `ViewPager.setClickable(false)` and `setEnabled()` don't work

```
disable clickable
// do something
enable clickable
```

How to do that?

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you are using TabLayout along with ViewPager. So, you need to implement as follows

```
LinearLayout tabStrip = ((LinearLayout) your_tab_layout.getChildAt(0));
for(int i = 0; i < tabStrip.getChildCount(); i++) {
    tabStrip.getChildAt(i).setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            return true;
        }
    });
}
```

For API 24 and above

```
your_tab_layout.clearOnTabSelectedListeners();
```

Hope this helps